# Faded text at bottom of div?

Tags: html, css

This works great:
[Fading out text at bottom of a section with transparent div, but height stays under section after overlaying div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837606/fading-out-text-at-bottom-of-a-section-with-transparent-div-but-height-stays-un)

How can it be expanded upon so it works on a scrollable div?

Applying `height: 100px; overflow: auto;` causes the `.fadeout` div to end up at the bottom of the scrollarea.

jsFiddle of what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/6k3vV/165/

Comment: Can you post a code example of what you got so we can fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6k3vV/167/

here. Need a parent with relative too

```
.fadeout {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 4em;
    background: linear-gradient(
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
    );
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
} 
section {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```