# Fade the end of the text

Tags: css, gradient

As it is there in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837606/fading-out-text-at-bottom-of-a-section-with-transparent-div-but-height-stays-un) question, I want to fade the text at the right and not the bottom.

This is what the user is doing

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
); 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
);
background-image: linear-gradient(
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
);
```

Comment: Probably because you haven't really shown what you've tried to do, or given a good explanation of what you want to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or just add `left`

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(`left`, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
```

```css
section {
  position: relative;
}
.fadeout {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor
    sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor
    sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <div class="fadeout"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is, add `90deg` and change the `bottom: 4em` to `bottom: 6em`(`height` and `bottom` values depend on the content's `height`).

```css
.fadeout {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 6em;
  height: 4em;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor
    sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <div class="fadeout"></div>
</section>
```